# How to correctly receive string in url format in ASP NET Core 3.1?

Tags: c#, api, asp.net-core, controller, asp.net-core-3.1

Lets say we have an API that receives URLs in one of its controllers actions. How is this doable in Net Core 3.1? If i understand correctly, then https://www.test.com/anothertest/test will mess up the routing to the controller?

Code example below

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class TestController : Controller
{
    [HttpPost("{url}")]
    public ActionResult<string> Post(string url)
    {
        // I want this to work! The url should be the full url specified i.e. https://www.myawesome.com/url/with/slashes
    }
}
```

So if i call https://localhost:5001/api/Test/https://www.url.com/with/slashes i would get https://www.url.com/with/slashes as the incoming url argument.

Comment: Hi @Tomato,do you want to get the url string in action?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you pass `https://www.url.com/with/slashes` as part of the url,"/" will be unrecognized.

Normally, the easiest way to pass the url is through querystring.

You can change your code like bellow.

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult<string> Post(string url)
    {
        //...
    }
```

Then the url should be

```
https://localhost:xxxxx/api/test/?url=https://www.url.com/with/slashes
```

Comment: Well, that's what i wanted to avoid :(. One small fix is that the url will be `https://localhost:xxxxx/api/test?url=https://www.url.com/with/slashes`